# Getting HttpErrorResponse Error Status 400 while calling Web Api

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

My Code is pretty simple and other calls with same design are working. Below is the [image: Error]  The http call is not hitting WEB API controller.

```
loginUser(login: ApiLoginDetails) {
    return this.http
      .post(`https://localhost:44314/api/users/login`, login)
      .pipe(catchError(error => this.errorHandler(error)));
 }
```

Here is the web api end point code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginUser(ApiLoginDetails login)
    {
        var isValidUser = await this.loginService.ValidateUserAsync(login.Username, login.Password);

        if (!isValidUser)
        {
            return this.BadRequest();
        }

        await this.loginService.SignInAsync(login.Username, false);

        return this.Ok();
    }
```

Comment: can you add your Web API endpoint code?

Comment: added the code @JasonWhite

Comment: is it possible that the `var isValidUser = await this.loginService.ValidateUserAsync(login.Username, login.Password);` is causing the error?  Error states "One or more validation errors occurred."

Comment: HTTP 400 is a Bad Request which is what you're returning `if (!isValiduser)`

Comment: My issue is - The call is not hitting controller at all

Comment: If that were true you would be getting a 404, not a 400. See also the error message, that is clearly from .net returning the api controller's model validation state. For whatever reason the passed in instance of `ApiLoginDetails` is not valid according to your validation attributes, (perhaps you have a action filter that is checking this). It is a server side error.

Comment: I tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54048880/get-errormessage-from-response-in-netcore-2-2-web-api and found something interesting. Now the action gets hit but the model is null. The model I am posting in Angular is coming as null. Not sure what is the reason. Any idea?

Comment: Change `ApiLoginDetails login` to `[FromBody]ApiLoginDetails login`